# Intuitive way to prove that $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \cdots = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, intuition, solution-verification, infinite-product

I’m trying to come up with an intuitive way to prove that $$\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \cdots = 0$$ That is, I want to prove that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(1)^n}{2}=0$$

I thought of this way. $$S= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \cdots$$ Multiply both sides by 2 to give $$2S= 1 \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \cdots$$ But $$2S=S$$ So $S=0$. Is this proof valid?

Comment: I would say no as that assumes that your product converges to something ahead of time.  You would first need to prove that it converges before you can use $S$ in any calculations.  Such a misuse of notation and setting something equal to something else leads to other errors such as saying that $1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: As @JMoravitz notes, this is fallacious since assigning a variable to the product assumes that there is a limit to the product. That being said, your method works IF you first show that the product converges.

Comment: That can be accomplished via the monotone convergence theorem., which states that a sequence that is monotone and bounded will necessarily converge.  Your sequence of partial products satisfies this as every partial product is strictly greater than 0 and partial products with more terms in the product are always at most half as large as partial products with fewer terms.

Comment: $1 + 2 + 4 + 8 +16 + ..... = S$ so $2S = 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32+...$ and $2S + 1 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16+32 + ..... = S$.   So $2S + 1= S$ so $S = -1$ and $1+2+4 + 8+ 16+....  =-1$. Is that valid.  Why or why not?

Comment: Just putting in my 2 cents: the OP asked for "intuitive". Well, one way to look at it is that this is basically $\frac 1{2^n}$ as $n \to \infty$. As $n$ increases, $2^n$ increases as well, so $\frac 1{2^n}$ must decrease as well, to $0$.

Comment: @DonThousand  But multiplication isn't addition.  As $\frac 12 < 1$ then $S_{n+1}=\frac 12 S_n < S_n$.  So converges. But  we need a reason it can't converge to something something larger than $0$. We can prove that if $(\frac 12)^n \to a > 0$ then for and $0< epsilon< a$ there is an $a < (\frac 12)^n< a+\epsilon$ but then $\frac 12 a< (\frac 12)^{n+1} < \frac 12 a +\frac 12\epsilon < a$ if $\epsilon < a$.  But now we are no longer "intuitive". But obviously $2^n\to \infty$ so $\frac 1{2^n}\to 0$. "intuitive" doesn't seem fruitful as the result is "intuitive" from the get go.

Comment: So, I frankly, just view this question as, is my intuitive proof valid.  And the answer to that is a very strong "no".  Other intuitive proofs are a dime a dozen.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_n = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac12 = \left(\frac12\right)^n$. Then $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} = \frac12<1$ so $\{p_n\}$ is decreasing, and the product of positive numbers is a positive number, so $p_n>0$ for all $n$. Since $p_n$ is decreasing and bounded below, it converges to its infimum. Now, given $\varepsilon>0$, we may choose a positive integer $N$ such that $N>\frac{\log \varepsilon}{\log\frac12}$. It follows that for $n\geqslant N$ we have
$$
p_n= \left(\frac12\right)^n <\varepsilon,
$$
so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n=0$.

Comment: This does not answer his question of why his proof is invalid.

Comment: So I figured I'd give a valid proof instead. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: No, it's totally valid. It may not give insight into his issue though (but it could help).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof doesn't quite work; limits are a bit tricky in that they can fail to exist, which means that there is an unfounded assumption when you write
$$S=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}2.$$
This assumes there is such a real number, which there might not be.

Note that the fact that the quantity being multiplied has absolute value less than $1$ is never used; you could equally well run your argument on the product of any real number infinitely many times; for instance, if I started with
$$S=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}2$$
I could multiply by $1/2$ to cancel the first term, exactly as you have done, to find $S=1/2S$ which implies $S=0$. However, when we multiply $2$ by itself over and over, the sum doesn't get closer to $0$ - it just gets bigger and bigger! So your argument does not work. It does establish, by similar reasoning that the product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}k$ either diverges or converges to $0$ whenever $k\neq 1$, though.

This said, you have shown that $0$ is the only possible value that the product could converge to - you do need to be careful with arguments like this, since, while your strategy of multiplying $S$ by $2$ and cancelling that $2$ with the first term is perfectly fine, it's easy to make mistakes when you write out infinite products and manipulate them like finite products - for instance, some products converge, but can be rearranged to converge to something else.

It's somewhat unavoidable that you have to do some analysis to prove your result; you are essentially trying to show that the sequence $(1/2)^n$ converges to $0$. This means that, noting that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $N$ such that $\left|(1/2)^n\right| < \varepsilon$ for every $n > N$. This is not so hard explicitly construct: if you set $N$ to be the ceiling of $\log_{1/2}(\varepsilon)$, you can verify that the sequence really does converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You're proof would work if we knew $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac 12)^n$ converges.

Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac 12)^n = L$ would mean $2L = 2\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac 12)^n =\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac 12)^{n+1}=\lim_{n-1\to \infty}(\frac 12)^{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac 12)^n = L$ so $2L = L$ and $L = 0$.

But we *NEED* to know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac 12)^n$ converges first.

(Counterexample is if $\lim_{n\to \infty} 1+ 2 + 4 + .... + 2^n = S$ then $2S+1 = 1+2\lim_{n\to \infty} 1+ 2 + 4 + .... + 2^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} 1+ 2 + 4 + .... + 2^{n+1} = S$ and so $S= -1$ which is clearly false as $\lim_{n\to \infty} 1+ 2 + 4 + .... + 2^n$ doesn't converge.)

I don't know how "intuitive this is but $0 < \frac 12 < 1=(\frac 12)^0$ and if $0 < (\frac 12)^n < (\frac 12)^{n-1}$ then $0 < (\frac 12)^n*\frac 12 < (\frac 12)^{n-1}*\frac 12$ so $0 < (\frac 12)^{n+1} < (\frac 12)^n$ so for $n\to \infty$ we have $(\frac 12)^n$ decreasing but bounded below by $0$.  So $\lim (\frac 12)^n$ must converge.

But I don't know how "intuitive" it is.

=======

Perhaps the safest both intuitive *and* valid is:

For any $0 < \epsilon < 1$ then $\frac 1{\epsilon} > 1$ and $N =\log_2{\frac 1\epsilon} > 1$.  If $n > N>\log_2{\frac 1\epsilon}>1$ then $2^n > 2^N > \frac 1\epsilon$.

So $2^N > \frac 1\epsilon$ for $n > N$.

So $0 < \frac 1{2^n} = (\frac 12)^n < \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac 12)^n = 0$.

....

Remember  $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = L$ means that we can always get $a_n$ and $L$ close enough together by taking $n$ large enough.

So if we want to get $0$ and $(\frac 12)^n$ closer than $\epsilon$ we just have to take $n > \log_2{\frac 1\epsilon}$.

=======

If that isn't "intuitive" enough

It should be intuitive that as $n\to \infty$ then $2^n \to \infty$ (but I don't like encouraging this approach because just because it is "intuitive" doesnt mean it is *true*). And it should be intuitive that as $m \to \infty$ that $\frac 1m \to 0$ (but again, ditto).  So  $n\to \infty\implies 2^n \to \infty \implies \frac 1{2^n} \to 0$.  That's intuitive.  And its valid.  But is it *allowed*?  I don't know.  Depends on your level.  I wouldn't accept it in and of itself; -- at least not the first  time.